# Dynamic Mapping for an object field that unwraps the parent path

Tags: elasticsearch

I am evaluating whether ElasticSearch can meet the needs of a new system I'm building. It looks amazing, so I'm really hopeful I can figure out a mapping strategy that works.

In this system, administrators can define fields to be associated with documents dynamically. So a given type (in the elasticsearch sense of the word) can have any number of fields, which I do not know the name of ahead of time. And each field can be of any type: int, date, string, etc.

An example document may look like:

```
{
    "name": "bob",
    "age": 22,
    "title": "Vice Intern",
    "tagline": "Ask not what your company can do for you, but..."
}
```

Notice that there are 2 string fields. Awesome. My problem though is that I want the "tagline" to be analyzed, but I do not want "title" to be analyzed.

Remember I don't know the names of these fields ahead of time. And there could be multiple fields of each type. So there could be 10 string fields of various names, 3 of which should be analyzed and 7 of which should not.

Another requirement I have is that the name the administrator gives the field should also be what they can search by. So, for example, if they want to find all the Vice Interns who have something to say, the lucene query may be:

```
+title:"Vice Intern" +tagline:"company"
```

So my thought was that I could define a dynamic mapping. Since I don't know the names of the fields ahead of time, it seems like a great approach. The key though is coming up with a way of differentiating string fields that should be analyzed and ones that shouldn't be!

I thought, hey, I'll just put all the fields that need analyzing into a nested object, like this:

```
{
    "name": "bob",
    "age": 22,
    "title": "Vice Intern",
    "textfields": {
        "tagline": "Ask not what your company can do for you, but...",
        "somethingelse": "lorem ipsum",
    }
}
```

Then, in my dynamic mapping, I have a way of mapping those fields differently:

```
{
    "mytype": {
        "dynamic_templates": {
            "nested_textfields": {
                "match": "textfields",
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "index": "analyzed",
                    "analyzer": "default"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that isn't right, I actually need some kind of nested mapping, but no matter, because if I understand it correctly, even if I got that working, it would mean those fields are searched for (via lucene syntax) like this:

```
+title:"Vice Intern" +textfields.tagline:"company"
```

And I don't want the "textfields" prefix. Since I'm the one providing the textfields object that wraps the text fields, I know that the fields within it are still uniquely named across the entire document.

I thought of using a pattern match instead. So instead of wrapping them in a "textfields" object, I could prefix them, like "textfield_tagline". But when doing that, the {name} token in the dynamic mapping includes the prefix, I don't see a way to just pull out the "*" portion.

Any solution which gets me the necessary behavior is a correct answer. Even if that involves nested mapping information into the documents themselves (can you do that? I've seen something like that, I think...).

EDIT:

I've attempted the following dynamic template. I'm trying to use index_name to remove the 'textfields.' in the index. This dynamic template just doesn't seem to match though, because after putting a document and looking at the mapping I see no analyzer specified.

```
    {
        "mytype" : {
            "dynamic_templates":
            [
            {
                "textfields": {
                    "path_match": "textfields.*",
                    "match_mapping_type" : "string",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "analyzed",
                        "analyzer": "default",
                        "index_name": "{name}",
                        "fields": {                 
                            "sort": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "index_name": "{name}_sort"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am learning about nested mappings and index_name. It seems like I should be able to give the nested properties (textfields.tagline) a root level index name by specifying its index_name. Not quite figured out yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to duplicate the results that you asked for specifically with the following index creation (with mappings), document, and search query. The type does vary a bit, but it serves the purpose of the example.

**Index Settings**

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/sandbox

{
 "settings": { 
   "index": {
     "number_of_shards": 1,
     "number_of_replicas": 0
   }
 },
 "mappings": {
   "mytype": {
     "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            "indexedfields": {
                "path_match": "indexedfields.*",
                "match_mapping_type" : "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "analyzed",
                    "analyzer": "default",
                    "index_name": "{name}",
                    "fields": {                 
                        "sort": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "index_name": "{name}_sort"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "textfields": {
                "path_match": "textfields.*",
                "match_mapping_type" : "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "index_name": "{name}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "strings": {
                "path_match": "*",
                "match_mapping_type" : "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }

        }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

**Document**

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/sandbox/mytype/1
{
   "indexedfields":{
      "hello":"Hello world",
      "message":"The great balls of the world are on fire"
   },
   "textfields":{
      "username":"User Name",
      "projectname":"Project Name"
   }
}
```

**Search**

```
POST http://localhost:9200/sandbox/mytype/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "message:\"great balls\""
    }
  },
   "filter":{
      "query":{
         "query_string":{
            "query":"username:\"User Name\""
         }
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":10,
   "sort":[

   ]
}
```

The search returns the following response:

```
{
   "took":2,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":1,
      "successful":1,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":1,
      "max_score":0.19178301,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"sandbox",
            "_type":"mytype",
            "_id":"1",
            "_score":0.19178301,
            "_source":{
               "indexedfields":{
                  "hello":"Hello world",
                  "message":"The great balls of the world are on fire"
               },
               "textfields":{
                  "username":"User Name",
                  "projectname":"Project Name"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It seems I had pretty much figured it out via the index_name thing. I thought it wasn't working because when I got the generated _mapping there was no 'indexed' mapping, only the non-indexed one. But as you told me offline, it's only because that's the default and it was omitting the defaults. Awesome.